# How to filter data with dropdown and ajax in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

My app features a dashboard where users can display and filter items from the database. Currently my controller selects all records from `Report` based on an array of `@assigned_user_ids`.

**dashboard_controller.rb index action**

```
@latest_report = Report.where.not(:assigned_user_id => nil).where(:assigned_user_id => @assigned_user_ids).where(reporting_date: Report.select('MAX(reporting_date)')).order(:assigned_user_id)
```

In the dashboard index view I have a `select_tag` where the user can select either `all` or just a specific `assigned_user_id`. The `select_tag` takes values from an `@employees` instance variable, that holds a selection of of available `assigned_user_ids`.

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= select_tag "teams", options_from_collection_for_select(@employees, "assigned_user_id", "full_name"), :include_blank => 'All'  %>
```

What I want to do now is to include ajax at this point so that the app performs the following steps:

- If a user selects a specific `assigned_user_id` filter `@latest_report` by this value and render it via ajax
- If a user selects `"All"` filter `@latest_report` by all available assigned_user_ids and render it via ajax

How can I achieve this (without using a gem)?

**UPDATE**
I managed to make it work with several `link_to` and a dedicated `route`. However I am confused to solve this problem with using a `select_tag` (as this does not link to my route that renders the partial via ajax) and also with the option to select "All".

Comment: You can create a partial for reports then request ajax with js format and render the partial with success response

Comment: This works if I have link_to instead of a select_tag. However I don't know how to achieve this with a select_tag and the option "All". Could you help?

Answer (score 2):

I will give the idea of populating the Select with Ajax, then you can apply to your case, alright?

First, you will need two files in your folder WHAT_WILL_BE_UPDATED views (In my example will be City - I will be updating city according to the State selected!):

```
Cities view
  -> _cities.html.erb
  -> update_city.js.coffee
```

In your partial _cities:

```
<% @city.all.each do |t| %>
  <option value="<%= t.id %>"><%= t.city_name %></option>
<% end %>
```

In your update_city.js.coffee file:

```
$("#select_city").empty()
  .append("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'cities/city', object: @city ) %>")

# Here, "#select_city" is the ID of your Select! So, we are basically empty your current Select and then populate with what you have in your partial _city.
```

To solve the ajax request, add this to your JS files in assets:

```
$ ->
  $(document).on 'change', '#state_id', (evt) ->
    $.ajax 
      url: '/cities/update_city'
      type: 'GET'
      dataType: 'script'
      data: {
        state_id: $("#state_id option:selected").val()
      }
      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}")
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        console.log("AJAX Sucesss: #{textStatus}")

# Here, we are add a "on change" event to your your Select responsible to trigger the Ajax call. In this example, the Select with id "state_id" is responsible. I'm passing as arguments to Ajax the value selected in the Select with id "state_id"!
```

In the city controller we have this:

```
def update_city
  @city = City.by_state(params[:state_id]).order(:city_name)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {render layout: false}
  end
end

private
  def city_params
    params.require(:city).permit(:state_id)
  end
```

In my view I would have these two select:

```
<%= m.label :state, "State" %>
<%= m.select(:state_id, State.select("id, name").order(:name).collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, { include_blank: false, selected: m.object.state_id}, { id: 'state_id' }) %>

<%= m.label :city, "City" %>
<%= m.select(:city_id, City.by_state(State.first.id).collect {|p| [ p.city_name, p.id ] }, { include_blank: false, selected: m.object.city_id }, { id: 'select_city' }) %>
```

I hope I could help you!
Good luck!

Comment: @Oliver my answer was helpful to you?